# MS Access 2010 VBA Multiple Else If Issues

Tags: ms-access, vba, if-statement

I have an MS Access form where the user can select up to four criteria to filter the records returned by a report. In the VBA, I'm trying to build my filter string dynamically based on which fields, if any, the user chose to filter by. The below code is giving me a "Block If without End If" error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
    strFilter = "Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
    If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
    End If
Else
If (IsNull(frm!sop) = False) Then
    strFilter = "sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"
    If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
        strFilter = "Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
    End If
Else
If (IsNull(frm!revision) = False) Then
    strFilter = "revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
    If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
        strFilter = " AND Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
    End If
Else
If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
    strFilter = "department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
    If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
        strFilter = " AND Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
    End If
    If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
    End If
End If
```

Any advice you could give me to improve this code would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm - I'm using it on Office 2010 with no issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code avoids " AND " at the beginning of `strFilter`.  However the logic is challenging to follow and it uses multiple variations on the same basic themes.

Use a simpler approach. You're interested in the values contained in 4 form controls:

- `frm!employee`
- `frm!sop`
- `frm!Revision`
- `frm!dept`

Examine each of them in turn and, for any which contain a value, add a segment starting with " AND " to `strFilter`.  Afterwards, if `strFilter` contains *any* text, you know it starts with " AND " so you can simply discard the first 5 characters.

```vb
strFilter = vbNullString ' <- make it explicit
If Len(Trim(frm!employee) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strFilter = strFilter & _
        " AND Trainee_First_Name & ' ' &  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & _
        frm!employee & "'"
End If
If Len(Trim(frm!sop) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"
End If
If Len(Trim(frm!Revision) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " AND revision_number = '" & _
        frm!Revision & "'"
End If
If Len(Trim(frm!dept) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
End If
If Len(strFilter) > 0 Then
    ' discard " AND " from beginning of string
    strFilter = Mid(strFilter, 6)
End If
MsgBox "strFilter ->" & strFilter & "<-"
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  I upvoted your answer because you helped him understand the statement blocking in his question, and I think that's a good thing.  Both answers are useful IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `else... if` clause aren't terminated with `end if`. You either need to use `ElseIf` or

```
Else
  If ...
  End If
Else...
```

I've modified your code below to use the latter syntax. Notice the **End If** lines below.

**Note: You don't need **, that's just to call attention to it in your code block!**

```
If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
        strFilter = "Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
        If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
        End If
    Else
    If (IsNull(frm!sop) = False) Then
        strFilter = "sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"
        If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
            strFilter = "Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
        End If


**End If**
    Else
    If (IsNull(frm!revision) = False) Then
        strFilter = "revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
        If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
            strFilter = " AND Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
        End If
    **End If**
    Else
    If IsNull(frm!dept) = False Then
        strFilter = "department = '" & frm!dept & "'"
        If (IsNull(frm!employee) = False) Then
            strFilter = " AND Trainee_First_Name + ' ' +  Trainee_Last_Name = '" & frm!employee & "'"
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!sop) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND sop_number = '" & frm!sop & "'"""
        End If
        If IsNull(frm!revision) = False Then
            strFilter = strFilter + " AND revision_number = '" & frm!revision & "'"
        End If
    **End If**
    End If
```